# Convert List to Dataset in C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, dataset

I am trying to Convert List to Dataset(Set of DataTables). But When I try this I got only 1 table. but according to my model It has to be 5 Tables. can anyone please advise me on this.

My Matrix Model

```
 public class MatrixModel
    {

        public class RootObject
        {

            public string responseId { get; set; }
            public string searchId { get; set; }
            public int totalFound { get; set; }
            public List<availableHotels> availableHotels { get; set; }
        }

        public class availableHotels
        {
            public string processId { get; set; }
            public string hotelCode { get; set; }
            public string availabilityStatus { get; set; }

            public double totalPrice { get; set; }
            public double totalTax { get; set; }

            public double totalSalePrice { get; set; }

            public string currency { get; set; }

            public string boardType { get; set; }
            public List<rooms> rooms { get; set; }



        }

        public class rooms
        {
            public string roomCategory { get; set; }
            public List<paxes> paxes { get; set; }
            public double totalRoomRate { get; set; }
            public List<ratesPerNight> ratesPerNight { get; set; }
        }

        public class paxes
        {
            public string paxType { get; set; }
            public int age { get; set; }


        }

        public class ratesPerNight
        {
            public string date { get; set; }
            public double amount { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

### Convert Json Response to List

```
   List<MatrixModel.RootObject> ddd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MatrixModel.RootObject>>("["+tstobj+"]");
```

Convert List to Dataset

---

```
DataSet dvv=ddd.ToDataSet<MatrixModel.RootObject>();


public static class ListConverter
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert our IList to a DataTable
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="list"></param>
        /// <returns>DataTable</returns>
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            Type elementType = typeof(T);
            using (DataTable t = new DataTable())
            {
                PropertyInfo[] _props = elementType.GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in _props)
                {
                    Type _pi = propInfo.PropertyType;
                    Type ColType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(_pi) ?? _pi;
                    t.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, ColType);
                }
                foreach (T item in list)
                {
                    DataRow row = t.NewRow();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in _props)
                    {
                        row[propInfo.Name] = propInfo.GetValue(item, null) ?? DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    t.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                return t;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert our IList to a DataSet
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="list"></param>
        /// <returns>DataSet</returns>
        public static DataSet ToDataSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ds.Tables.Add(list.ToDataTable());
                return ds;
            }
        }



    }
```

---

I got only One DataTable . 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you want to convert hierarchical data to relational and that can not be done this easily. For example in your current hierarchical model you store a `List` of `availableHotels` for each `RootObject`, but in a relational DB (like a `DataSet`) you should store all the `availableHotels` objects in a separate table then add a `RootObjectId` column to this table and for each row set it to the id of the `RootObject` object that is the parent of the `availableHotels` stored in this row. And so on for the rest of your data.

This will need a totally different approach than the one you used in your code.

And of course you shouldn't put `using` on the newly created objects if you want to `return` and use them outside your method because it will dispose them.

Comment: +1 and...from OP code only one table is/should be returned. One row for each item in list but everything inside one single table

Comment: Exaclty. There is nothing in the code that would create more than one table.